# send data from socket to c# in android

Tags: c#, android, sockets, gps

I am trying to develop an application in android to sent the gps data to my pc .the android part is :

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    float latitude = (float) (location.getLatitude());
    float longitude = (float) (location.getLongitude());
    showMessage("Student Details", "Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude);

    Log.i("Geo_Location", "Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude);


    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.5",5000);
        DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DOS.writeUTF("HELLO_WORLD");
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
```

And the c# code or server code is :

```
 public AsyncCallback pfnWorkerCallBack;
    private Socket m_mainSocket;
    private Socket[] m_workerSocket = new Socket[25];
    private int m_clientCount = 0;
    private string ipaddress;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        startfun();
    }
    public void startfun()
    {
        try
        {
            // DrawMapPersian();
            ipaddress = "192.168.1.5";
            // Check the port value

            string portStr = "5000";
            int port = System.Convert.ToInt32(portStr);
            // Create the listening socket...
            m_mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                      SocketType.Stream,
                                      ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            // Bind to local IP Address...
            m_mainSocket.Bind(ipLocal);

            listBox1.Items.Add("Server Started...");
            // Start listening...
            m_mainSocket.Listen(20);
            listBox1.Items.Add("Server Listening for ...");

            // Create the call back for any client connections...
            m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
        }
        catch (Exception qqq)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer =
    new StreamWriter(@"e:\a.txt"))
            {
                writer.Write(qqq.Message);

            }
        }
    }



   public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            try
            {
                SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;

                int iRx = 0;
                // Complete the BeginReceive() asynchronous call by EndReceive() method
                // which will return the number of characters written to the stream 
                // by the client
                iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
                string res = GetParameters(socketData.dataBuffer);

                Console.WriteLine(res.ToString());
}
```

another thing that i should say i add this permissions to manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

I connected the mobile phone to the wireless network ,i mean the mobile can access my ip .
The problem is the gps data is generated so slowly i don't know why ?another problem is the android application doesn't send any data to server ,

Comment: Some part of code in server is missing if you need that i will paste it

Comment: You are not sending Lat and Lon. Why not?

Comment: `is the android application doesn't send any data to server ,` How do you know? Or do you mean that the server isn't receiving anything? You should start to check if a connection is made by the client. Now is there?

Comment: @greenapps i know because i just want to test my connection if it works i will send my gps data

Comment: @greenapps i listen the port in server and unfortunately i don't receive any data

Comment: You forgot to answer one of my questions.

Comment: `Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.5",5000);`I asked you if there is a connection made. Doesnt your program crash with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Comment: @greenapps i fact i don't know the android application makes a connection with the server .

Comment: @greenapps when i open my page in android the application crashed ,

Comment: Why did you not tell that in your post? From the start! `problem is the android application doesn't send any data to server ,`. No. Of course it will not if it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

**Client**

To accelerate the location update, you have to specify to the Activity the location update interval when setting the `LocationListener`  implementation.
Something like :

```
LocationListener impl = new MyLocationListenerImpl();
long interval = 4000;//change your code here
setLocationListener(impl, interval);
```

(Note that the code above is more like a pseudo code, since It's been a long time since I have touched LocationListener).

**Server**

The code you provided does not mention the "OnDataReceived" member function. So I think that you should dig in this way.

Unless sockets are used on purpose, consider using Http Protocol and frameworks like ASP.NET and loopj Async Http to pass data to a server, it's easier !